Abnormal Behavour of BottomAppBar in Flutter
I am encountering an abnormal behaviour of FloatingActionButton and BottomAppBar enter image description here,
Problems i am facing are that the notch is not in the center and the also the row's childern are not in the center
Here is the code,
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      backgroundColor: gray70,
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          child: BottomAppBar(
            height: 60,
            color: gray60,
            surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
            shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.square_grid_2x2),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.calendar),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.creditcard),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I want to achieve the similar Effect enter image description here

Remove that Padding above ClipRRect, that's the cause of that weird behavior.
If you really want the navigation bar to be padded, i suggest to customize it (build it in the body).
Hope it helps you.
